# default navigationbar reduce the size of uiview in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

I have been using default `navigationbar` in my app. I have an image with size 320X460 as background image for my `view`. Since i set top bar as `navigationbar`(320x44) in xib, my view's size became (320X416).So the image does not suit for background. For me, its necessary to use default `navigationbar` instead of custom navigation bar. can i set default `navigationbar` by overlapping the current view without reducing its size (320X460)?

Comment: Add UIScroollView and add image on UIScrollView

Comment: best way to fit the situation is reduce the size of image from (320x460) to (320x416) to fit in your background exactly.